# Taking ints with scanf into a memory allocation during a while loop and realloc'ing

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, realloc

I declare an int pointer and give it a memory allocation. I then feed ints into it until the user inputs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. The loop works fine unless I try to input 7 or more, at which point it gives me an error that looks like "realloc(): invalid next size" and gives me a backtrace/memory map. It has to have something to do with my `realloc` line but I'm not sure what. Can anybody enlighten me?

```
int  n= 0, *x, i;
double mean = 0.0, median = 0.0, stdDev = 0.0;

x =  malloc(sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; scanf("%d", &x[i]) != -1; i++) {
        n++;
        x = realloc(x, n+1 * sizeof(int));
        mean = findMean(x, n);
        median = findMedian(x, n);
        stdDev = findStandardDeviation(x, n, mean);
}
```

Comment: `for(i = 0; scanf("%d", &x[i]) != -1; i++) { ... }` is an infinite loop should the user enter non-numeric text.  Suggest `for(i = 0; scanf("%d", &x[i]) == 1; i++) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is order of operations: `n + 1 * sizeof(int)` means "multiply 1 times the sizeof(int), then add n". You can use parentheses to enforce order: `(n + 1) * sizeof(int)`.

Memory allocations can be expensive! Ask for a reasonable chunk of memory, then increase it every so often by a factor of, say, 2. On a memory allocation system call, the OS may give you a larger block than you asked for so that subsequent `realloc` calls are less expensive and use memory already available to your program.

It's good to check that your `malloc` and `realloc` calls succeeded. These functions return NULL if the allocation request failed.

Also, don't forget to `free` your allocated memory when you finish with it to avoid memory leaks.

It might be a fun exercise to write your own "vector/ArrayList/list"-like interface that expands and contracts to size and possibly features operations like `slice(start_index, end_index)` and `remove(index)`.

Here's a full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int nums_len = 0;
    int nums_capacity = 5;
    int *nums = malloc(nums_capacity * sizeof(int));

    while (scanf("%d", &nums[nums_len]) != -1) {
        if (++nums_len >= nums_capacity) {
            printf("increasing capacity from %d to %d\n", 
                   nums_capacity, nums_capacity * 2);

            nums_capacity *= 2;
            nums = realloc(nums, nums_capacity * sizeof(int));

            if (!nums) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d: realloc failed\n", 
                        __func__, __LINE__);
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        printf("got: %d\n", nums[nums_len-1]);
    }

    printf("Here are all of the %d numbers you gave me:\n", nums_len);

    for (int i = 0; i < nums_len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    free(nums);
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run:

```
5
got: 5
6
got: 6
7
got: 7
8
got: 8
1
increasing capacity from 5 to 10
got: 1
3
got: 3

5
got: 5
6
got: 6
7
got: 7
1
increasing capacity from 10 to 20
got: 1
2
got: 2
3
got: 3
4
got: 4
5
got: 5
6
got: 6
67
got: 67
8
got: 8
1
got: 1
2
got: 2
3
increasing capacity from 20 to 40
got: 3
4
got: 4
1
got: 1
2
got: 2
Here are all of the 23 numbers you gave me:
5 6 7 8 1 3 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 67 8 1 2 3 4 1 2
```

Comment: Thank you for that. How would you go about not reallocating every time? just an if statement with i%5==0 or something like that? also do i free() after every realloc()?

Comment: Reallocs are not allways that expensive. First, every malloc/realloc are not system calls, they request memory from the os in very large chunks. They then give them to the program in smaller pieces without doing any system call. And `realloc` is often only a size-update without moving the content. That is especially true if the memory being "realloced" is the last memory being allocated.

Comment: @user3242445 No--just one free for the pointer. I added an example of periodic realloc. Does this help clarify?

Comment: @ggorlen yes that helps! but now i'm just getting in 0's regardless of my input, lol.. oh dear

Comment: Strange. Check it out on https://repl.it/repls/AbandonedAuthorizedDecimal and see if it works for you there.

Comment: yup it's still doing it.. i'll update my code above

Comment: I'd recommend rolling back your edit, then posting your updated code separately (if at all). Otherwise, the answers become invalid and future visitors won't be able to glean much from the question. The problem in your updated code is poor variable naming--you're using both `i` and `n` to handle indexing and length logic on your array. Best to use a more explicit name as I did, which will eliminate confusion about which variable means what.

Answer (score 1):

`n+1 * sizeof(int)` is not the same as `(n+1) * sizeof(int)`